# Simplify $ab' + ( a'+b )c$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Boolean algebra
How to solve it. I am stuck after first step which is $ab' +(ab')'c$. After that I couldn't get the exact answer.

The answer is  $ab' + c.$

Comment: You can use again De Morgan's law from here (in the other 'direction' than you used it.

Comment: This is a particular case of $x+x'y=x+y$. Follow Marc Dinh's clue to prove this.

Comment: Yeah. Right. Thanks

Comment: Tell me if this is the right approach.  Y = ab' + (a'+b)c      Y = ab' + ( a'+b) c        Y= (ab'+(ab')') (ab'+c).        Y= (ab'+c)

Answer (score 1):

HINT

It is $k+k'c=k(c+c')+k'c,$ where $k=ab'.$ Can you finish it now?

Comment: Yeah. I did. I got ab'c + ab'c' + (ab')c' . After that -- c ( ab' + (ab')') + ab'c' . Then  -- c + ab'c'

Answer (score 0):

$$ab'+(ab')'c = (ab'+(ab')')(ab'+c)=1(ab'+c)=ab'+c$$